# How to rewrite url to use php script properly

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a php script that redirects external url, this is the script

```
<?php
 header("Refresh: 5; url={$_GET['url']}"); 
 echo 'You are redirecting to ... page'; 
?>
```

That redirects with this url

> http://my-domain.com/url.php?url=http://www.google.com

I wanted to rewrite this url with .htaccess so i added a code in my .htaccess file, this one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^url/(.*)$ /url.php?url=$1 [L]
```

So after adding this code, it should redirect with this url

> http://my-domain.com/url/?http://www.google.com

Script is working but it's not redirecting to external url, Just one message is appearing that is **You are redirecting to ... page** and it's just keep reloading the page at 5 seconds.

So what's the problem? It's with the script or by .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that query string is not part of RewriteRule test uri.

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^url/$ /url.php?url=%1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: still not works giving me "403 forbidden error" :( When script redirects to external domain!

Comment: It's a problem in your script